# Avoid doubling memory when loading and flipping Android Bitmap as OpenGL texture?

Tags: android, opengl-es

When loading OpenGL texture data on Android, to cope with the difference in coordinate systems between Android and OpenGL the typical pattern I see is to flip the Bitmap before uploading it:

```
Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(...);
Matrix flip = new Matrix();
flip.postScale(1f, -1f);
Bitmap toUpload = Bitmap.createBitmap(original, ..., flip, true);
original.recyle();
```

Unfortunately for a brief amount of time the memory required for these bitmaps is doubled because both the original and flipped version are resident. This is problematic for very large images such as texture atlases.

Is there a clever way to avoid this doubling? e.g., manipulating the original in place, or loading and transforming in a single step? Of course I can always manipulate the source data (i.e., pre-flip the images) or texture mapping (i.e., invert the V coordinates) but I'd prefer to tackle this issue during image load time as a way of separating concerns.

Comment: I don't know the `Bitmap` classes you use, but assuiming it allows random access to the image data, you could of course flip the data in-place - if you want to, one byte at a time. Another option would be uploading each image line separately with`glTexSubImage2D`.

Comment: Yes, true, manual manipulation is always an option. I fear it may be too slow to be viable but I'll have to make that determination experimentally.

Answer (score 1):

As an extreme example, working with mobile VR, the image and video source content is usually in some arbitrary format, depending on what tool was used to produce it.

VR content is so large that transforming the image pixels (like flipping) is not practical. It is far more efficient to just insert transforms into the GL pipeline.

Transforming the vertices and UV mappings of the 3D objects, as you say does not preserve a nice clean separation of concerns, but it is by far the optimal way to resolve image formatting problems. Yes, it can get ugly inserting customized transforms into the pipeline.

Of course if you have the option, the images can be pre-transformed in an editor, specifically for your app, to keep your pipeline nice and clean.